Error when deploying Github in Heroku for a TelegramBot in Python
Dos anyone know why this error appear when I deploy GitHub in Heroku for a TelegramBot?
Here the link to my GitHub
`2024-07-04T06:38:39.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user elledayz@gmail.com
2024-07-04T06:38:39.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user elledayz@gmail.com
2024-07-04T06:38:55.478865+00:00 app[api]: Release v35 created by user elledayz@gmail.com
2024-07-04T06:38:55.478865+00:00 app[api]: Deploy 08347330 by user elledayz@gmail.com
2024-07-04T06:38:55.530286+00:00 app[api]: Release v36 created by user elledayz@gmail.com
2024-07-04T06:38:55.530286+00:00 app[api]: Deploy 08347330 by user elledayz@gmail.com
2024-07-04T06:38:58.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2024-07-04T06:38:58.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2024-07-04T06:39:03.021098+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/" host=bot-telegram-team-7a85d2e1bab2.herokuapp.com request_id=410d3f57-251c-4d6b-aea0-f21ed5bea9df fwd="84.46.29.2" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2024-07-04T06:39:03.856405+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=bot-telegram-team-7a85d2e1bab2.herokuapp.com request_id=a8494a3b-b79c-402a-8259-8a2d8aef9571 fwd="84.46.29.2" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https`


Are you using windows? If so, you're potentially missing something

Hello Mike! now the following error when I fix the error shown arises "  at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=bot-telegram-team-7a85d2e1bab2.herokuapp.com request_id=5336e90b-c54c-419e-b945-6fb50c2f1a75 fwd="84.46.29.2" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https!

This has now become a different question, please post another one. There are many answers, such as this one. Also, make sure you read the documentation for deploying on Heroku; as with all systems and technologies, it will answer most of your questions.

@MikeK, that's just for local development. Heroku still uses Procfile when deploying.

I think your Heroku Dynos is not running
List the dynos for an app

heroku ps

Start worker dynos

heroku ps:scale web=1

EDIT:
Type these above lines in Heroku CLI

In which document from the GitHub i have to include this?

@Ele, that doesn't go in any file. It's not part of your application. It's a command that changes how Heroku is running your application—you can scale to more or fewer dynos at any time without rebuilding your app.
